# I try to get 2 frames from picamera. Why it works very slowly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi3, opencv3.0

From `picamera.PiCamera()` Thread I try to get `cls.frameCV2 = snap.array` for handling in opencv, and another `cls.frame = stream.read()` for web streaming. Both work, but very slowly.

What is the problem? If Use only `frameCV2` it works quite fast, or if I only Use `stream.read`, it also ok.

Here is my code snippet:

```
import time
import io
import threading
import cv2
import picamera
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray

class Camera(object):
    thread = None  # background thread that reads frames from camera
    frame = None  # current frame is stored here by background thread
    frameCV2 = None # same, but as a numpy array
    last_access = 0  # time of last client access to the camera

    def initialize(self):
        if Camera.thread is None:
            # start background frame thread
            Camera.thread = threading.Thread(target=self._thread)
            Camera.thread.start()

            # wait until frames start to be available
            while self.frame is None:
                time.sleep(0)

    def get_frame(self):
        Camera.last_access = time.time()
        self.initialize()
        return self.frame

    def get_frame_for_internal_proc(self): # store frame for cv2 я добавил
        Camera.last_access = time.time()
        self.initialize()
        return self.frameCV2

    @classmethod
    def _thread(cls):
        with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
            # camera setup
            camera.resolution = (800, 600)
            camera.hflip = True
            camera.vflip = True

            # let camera warm up
            camera.start_preview()
            time.sleep(2)

            rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera) # я добавил

            stream = io.BytesIO()
            for snap in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, 'bgr',
                                                 use_video_port=True):
                cls.frameCV2 = snap.array # frame for cv2

                # store frame for web
                camera.capture(stream, format='jpeg')
                stream.seek(0)
                cls.frame = stream.read()

                # reset stream for next frame
                stream.seek(0)
                stream.truncate()

                rawCapture.truncate(0)

                # if there hasn't been any clients asking for frames in
                # the last 10 seconds stop the thread
                if time.time() - cls.last_access > 10:
                    break
        cls.thread = None
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I didn't find the way to make it working faster. The main reason of low speed is doubled capturing inside of `camera.capture_continuous` circle.

Anyhow I solved the problem using 1 thread for both generation `frame` and `frameCV2`, just converting second one to the first. I just put `self.frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', self.frameCV2)[1].tobytes()`  in `get_frame()` method which converts numpy matrix to format, fit for web streaming.

Now it works well.